# Trying to pass values from jquery to php file using XMLHttpRequest()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am trying to pass values in an HTML textarea to a PHP file using jQuery. This is what I have so far:

**JQuery**

```
var jq = $.noConflict();
jq("#addUsers").click(function () {
    jq("#addModal").modal("show");
});

jq("#addUser").click(function () {
    var text = jq("textarea#emails").val();
    if (text.length == 0)
    {
        alert("Please enter new user e-mails line by line.");
    }
    else
    {
        var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200)
            {
                jq("textarea#emails").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        };
        xmlhttp.open("GET", "add_users.php?emails=" + text + "&list=1", true);
        xmlhttp.send(null);
    }
});
```

**add_users.php**

```
<?php
//error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');

$list = $_REQUEST["list"];
$emails = trim($_REQUEST["emails"]);

// This is where I will parse out the text line-by-line
// .....
?>
```

So, this is all activated by the click function on line 6. When I do this however, *nothing happens*. I tried putting an echo statement pretty much everywhere inside the function and it echoes out fine. Additionally:

- The php file is in the same directory as the file I'm working with.
- I've tried echoing out in the php file; the php file is never accessed.
- I've tried echoing out the response text using alert(); nothing happens.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Help please!!

Comment: that's a really weird mix of jquery and vanilla javascript

Comment: You already use jquery , why not use jquery `$.ajax` instead of vanilla javascript for xmlttp request?

Comment: It uses pure javascript to the complex tasks and jquery for the simple tasks. Commonly is the opposite.

Comment: Open your browser's developer tools. Look at the console. Are there any messages? Look at the Network tab. Does any request get made? Is it formatted as you expect? Do you get a response?

Comment: What does the HTML look like? How does it relate to the script element that loads the JavaScript?

Comment: If you put an alert in the click handler, but outside the Ajax handler, does it fire? i.e. is the function being called at all?

Comment: @Quentin Looks like a request to the php file was made. Status is 200.

Comment: @Quentin and yes alert() fires inside and outside the ajax handler.

Comment: see my answer below. you have an issue with how you're trying to output the results, fix that and see where you are at.

Comment: @jszobody lol sorry, this is my first time working with jquery

Comment: @jszobody Your method seems to work. Thanks! I am sure there are other ways to do it using $.ajax, but this is functional for now!

Comment: Yes you can absolutely use the `$.ajax` method as well, that would work. It's just more code, and `$.load` is a shortcut for these exact situations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For one, `jq("textarea#emails").innerHTML` is not going to work because you're dealing with a jQuery wrapped element now, and not a raw HTML element. If you use jQuery you want to set the contents with `val()` or `html()` (depending on the element).

So it's possible you *are* calling your script successfully, and just not outputting the results on your page.

You can simplify your ajax tremendously by using jQuery. I'd use `load()` specifically, since your intent is to stick the results into an element.

I would start with this:

```
jq("#addUser").click(function () {
    var text = jq("textarea#emails").val();
    if (text.length == 0)
    {
        alert("Please enter new user e-mails line by line.");
    }
    else
    {
        jq("textarea#emails").load("add_users.php?emails=" + text + "&list=1");
    }
});
```

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/load/

Once you have your ajax query working successfully, check your Dev Tools Network tab (assuming Chrome here) to watch the ajax call and see how your server is responding.

Comment: This doesn't appear to address the problem. You're recommending throwing out all the code and using a different method, but you haven't identified why it is failing in the first place or if this will help at all. It should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @Quentin eh, maybe. he asked how to send values from jquery to php... and I'm showing him how. his issue is quite possibly related to his convoluted code. generally simplifying things helps identify the real issue!

Comment: The question title asks how to do that, then the rest of the question shows an implementation that should work. Answers should take into account the whole question, not throw it out in favour of just addressing the title. While simplifying things in the way you suggest *might* help identify the real issue, and answer would explain how to deal with that real issue (which you can't because you haven't identified it).

Comment: @Quentin actually no, his implementation should not work. `jq("textarea#emails").innerHTML` is invalid. that's part of what I refactored. he will not get any output with that line of code, but he might with my answer. sheesh.

Comment: And if you'd explained that in the first place then it would have been an answer.